# MacOS newbie - Can't run flutter command from CMD?

Tags: flutter, path, zsh

I want to run `flutter` SDK from CDN, but it's not possible.
I followed the instructions on how to update the path to the flutter bin dir, but that is not working.

[image]

[image]

I have restarted my laptop but still doesn't work. Help! :)

Comment: Your final assignment to `PATH` *overwrote* the value of `PATH`, rather than augmenting the existing value. `~/Documents/flutter/bin` is not on your path once `.zshrc` is finished being sourced.

Comment: (Also, environment variables are better defined in `.zprofile` or `.zshenv` rather than in `.zshrc`.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My preferred way to install terminal applications is to use [homebrew](https://brew.sh/):

```
/bin/bash -c "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/HEAD/install.sh)"
```

you can then install flutter using homebrew as follows:

```
brew install --cask flutter
```